# How to create a pseudo element in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

In React Native, I have a box with an `absolute` position, and I'm placing another box after it. The only way that I know how to do this in CSS is by using a pseudo element [like in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yumxg9ym/) and this:

CSS:

```
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#parent::before {
  content: '';
  width: 60%;                           
  height: 60%;                         
}

#div1 {
  background: green;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;                            
  top: 50%;                             
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);      
}

#div2 {
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

So how can I do the same thing in React Native? Can I have a pseudo element?

Comment: Well, then show the simpler way. However, I suspect that you don't know how to do the same thing while using `absolute` in a simpler way.

Comment: Yea, that's not what I meant. `div1` has to be `absolute`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with react native...